Retrieve raw HTTP headers in node.js http module
I'm trying to get the raw HTTP headers of an incoming request in the node.js HTTP module. I want to extract the request line:
GET / HTTP/1.1
However, there doesn't seem to be a way to do it.
I'm instead using a format: ${req.method} ${req.url} HTTP/${req.httpVersion} to do it.
I looked through the Node http module docs for information on the headers, but I couldn't find a way to extract the raw headers from the request.
Is there a way to do it in vanilla Node?
The reason I want to get the request line is to test what happens if I make a request with invalid headers.

If there's no property on the request object with this exact line, then the only way to intercept it is to start your own TCP server, store the line and forward the sream to an underlying HTTP server. Not super easy but doable.

Since you are using node's http module, you can get the headers with req.getHeaders().
See the docs: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#requestgetheaders

This doesn't work for extracting the raw headers. Also, that's for outgoing requests, not incoming requests.
